# Can't install matplotlib, says is not a supported wheel

Tags: python-3.x

4, downloaded matplotlib file 2.0 cp34 amd64. I have x32 windows but it's not working, I tried downloading the other versions and running it but same problem. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install it with the python package manager pip.

```
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

See [this page](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#installing-windows) for more information regarding matplotlib installation on windows.

Comment: thanks now working, but now I'm getting import error: matplot requires dateutil, i ran through the other threads on this but not working, any ideas on how to fix it?